# How to configure agetty to autologon on only one terminal

Tags: tty, autologin

Running ubuntu server, I've reconfigured `/lib/systemd/system/getty@.service` to

```
[Service]
# the VT is cleared by TTYVTDisallocate
#                       ##ADDED THIS HERE##
ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty -a diagnosticuser --noclear %I $TERM
Type=idle
Restart=always
RestartSec=0
UtmpIdentifier=%I
TTYPath=/dev/%I
TTYReset=yes
TTYVHangup=yes
TTYVTDisallocate=yes
KillMode=process
IgnoreSIGPIPE=no
SendSIGHUP=yes
```

so that I could have my fancy little device automatically log in to a user whose shell is a diagnostic menu.  The problem is that all the consoles automatically log in to that user now.

Is there a way to get just the first one to log in, and leave the rest with a regular log-in prompt?  (can I have my cake as well as eat it?)

I was thinking, maybe I'd replace the "/sbin/agetty" with something that checks whether or not the "diagnosticuser" is already logged in.  But I was a little confused by the hyphen in "-/sbin/agetty" and I didn't want to take my chances.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new file for terminal 1 '/lib/systemd/system/getty@tty1.service' and copy into it the config you defined above.

In /lib/systemd/system/getty@.service use the following:

ExecStart=-/sbin/agetty --noclear %I $TERM

Console 1 will autologin as diagnosticuser all other consoles will prompt for credentials.